# Async methods wait for each other

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I am trying to run async program. 
There is main:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunTestsAsync().Wait();
    }

    private async static Task RunTestsAsync()
    {
        var a = new SlowString("ab", true);
        var b = new SlowString("c", true);

        var result1 = a.Equal(b);
        var result2 = b.Last(b);
        var result3 = b.GreaterThen(a);

        result1.Wait();
        result2.Wait();
        result3.Wait();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Results: {0},   {1},   {2}", result1.Result, result2.Result, result3.Result);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
}
```

And here is second file:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
class SlowString
{
    private readonly string str;
    private readonly bool msg;
    private readonly int delay;

    public SlowString(string str, bool msg = false, int delay = 30)
    {
        this.str = str;
        this.msg = msg;
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Equal(SlowString other)
    {
        if(msg) Console.WriteLine("SlowString Equals Started");

        Task.Delay(delay).Wait();
        bool result = await Task.Run(() => { return str.Equals(other.str); });

        if (msg) Console.WriteLine("SlowString Equals Ended");

        return result;
    }

    public async Task<bool> GreaterThen(SlowString other)
    {
        if (msg) Console.WriteLine("SlowString GreaterThen Started");

        Task.Delay(delay).Wait();
        bool result = await Task.Run(() => { return str.CompareTo(other.str) > 0 ? true : false; });

        if (msg) Console.WriteLine("SlowString GreaterThen Ended");

        return result;
    }

    public async Task<SlowString> Last(SlowString other)
    {
        if (msg) Console.WriteLine("SlowString Last Started");

        Task.Delay(delay).Wait();
        SlowString result = await Task.Run(() => { return str.CompareTo(other.str) > 0 ? this : other; });

        if (msg) Console.WriteLine("SlowString Last Ended");

        return result;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return str;
    }
}
}
```

Problem is my program always waits for previous computation to be completed, so I get:

> SlowString Equals Started 
>   SlowString Equals Ended 
>   SlowString Last Started 
>   SlowString Last Ended 
>   SlowString GreaterThen Started 
>   SlowString GreaterThen Ended

Even with greater delay, like 3000ms program stil waits until result1 is computed, 
then goes to result2 and computes it, and only then goes further. 
 
I think I've really tried everything. Please give me some clue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `.Wait()`, which, as the name would suggests, waits until the task is completed. It *blocks* the execution. So first thing would be *never* call `.Wait()` or `.Result` or any of the like. *Always* use `await` with your `async` methods.

But simply changing `.Wait()` to `await` won't do, as you're trying to run the tasks in parallel. In that case your routine should look more like:

```
var result1 = Task.Run(() => a.Equal(b));
var result2 = Task.Run(() => b.Last(b));
var result3 = Task.Run(() => b.GreaterThen(a));

await Task.WhenAll(new [] {result1, result2, result3});
```

On other notes:

```
Task.Delay(delay).Wait();
```

should also be

```
await Task.Delay(delay);
```

And lines like this:

```
bool result = await Task.Run(() => { return str.CompareTo(other.str) > 0 ? true : false; });
```

don't do anything other than apply an overhead: you're calling a new task on the thread pool and immediately awaiting the result. It's synchronous wrapped in an artificial asynchronicity. This:

```
bool result = str.CompareTo(other.str) > 0 ? true : false;
```

would probably run quicker, because of the lack of an overhead.

And your `Main` method should be:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await RunTestsAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I though Task.Delay(delay).Wait() means same as await Task.Delay(delay).

Comment: They're similar, but not the same. For a short explanation - always use _await_. 

For more in depth on `async`/`await` and blocking, I'll redirect you to the Stephen Cleary's blog:
https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html